# Rspec to have(n).items undefined method

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I'm trying to follow a guide [on code.tuts](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec--net-21297) and I keep getting an error.

Here is my Library spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Library do
  before :all do
    lib_arr = [
      Book.new("JavaScript: The Good Parts", "Douglas Crockford", :development),
      Book.new("Dont Make me Think", "Steve Krug", :usability),
    ]

    File.open "books.yml", "w" do |f|
      f.write YAML::dump lib_arr
    end
  end

  before :each do
    @lib = Library.new "books.yml"
  end

  describe  "#new" do
    context "with no parameters" do
      it "has no book" do
        lib = Library.new
        expect(lib).to have(0).books
      end
    end

    context "with a yaml file name parameters" do
      it "has two books" do
        expect(@lib).to_have(0).books
      end
    end
  end

  it "returns all the books in a given category" do
    expect(@lib.get_books_in_category(:development).length).to eql 1
  end

  it "accepts new books" do
    @lib.add_book(Book.new("Designing for the Web", "Mark Boulton", :design))
    expect(@lib.get_book("Designing for the Web")).to be_an_instance_of Book
  end

  it "saves the library" do
    books = @lib.books.map { |book| book.title}
    @lib.save
    lib2 = Library.new 'books.yml'
    books2 = lib2.books.map { |book| book.title }
    expect(books).to eql books2
  end
end
```

I'm getting that `have` is undefined. I've figured out it's my lines

```
expect(@lib).to have(0).books
expect(lib).to have(0).books
```

Is my syntax out of date? I've googled and I can't find it.

Comment: Rspec 3? Perhaps there is no [such matchers at now](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/all-matcher). Use size eq

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `have`/`have_exactly`, `have_at_least` and `have_at_most` matchers were removed from RSpec 3. They're now in the separate [rspec-collection_matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers) gem.

Or, as zishe says, instead of installing the gem, you can just use `eq` instead of `have`/`have_exactly`, and `be >=` instead of `have_at_least` and `be <=` instead of `have_at_most`.

Source: https://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/

Comment: @br3nt, RSpec 2 make too much ways for one thing,that's hard for beginner