# RSpec undefined method "errors_on"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have the following model that I want to test with RSpec:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dvds
  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

**language_spec.rb**

```
describe Language do
  describe 'title validation' do
    context 'title is present' do
      before(:each) do
        @lang = Language.new(title: 'English')
      end

      it 'is valid with present title' do
        expect(@lang).to have_exactly(0).errors_on(:title)
      end
    end

    context 'title is not present' do
      before(:each) do
        @lang = Language.create
      end

      it 'has an error on title attribute' do
        expect(@lang).to have_exactly(1).errors_on(:title)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately I'm getting test failures:

> Failures:
>
> 1) Language title validation title is present is valid with present
>   title
>        Failure/Error: expect(@lang).to have_exactly(0).errors_on(:title)
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `errors_on' for #<Language:0xaa40e98>
>        # ./spec/models/language_spec.rb:9:in`block (4 levels) in '
>
> 2) Language title validation title is not present has an error on
>   title attribute
>        Failure/Error: expect(@lang).to have_exactly(1).errors_on(:title)
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `errors_on' for #<Language id: nil, title: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>        # ./spec/models/language_spec.rb:19:in`block (4 levels) in '

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Pagination plugin
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'

# Testing
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 3.0.1"
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.4.1"
end

group :test do
  gem "faker", "~> 1.3.0"
  gem "capybara", "~> 2.3.0"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 1.3.0"
  gem "launchy", "~> 2.4.2"
  gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.42.0"
end
```

Any ideas why I'm getting `undefined method "errors_on"`?

Comment: There is no such matcher in Rspec 3. Maybe [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/948#issuecomment-44097307) will help.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But my error messages was a little bit different, so I thought there might be something else. In my situation I have to add to my Gemfile: `gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'`

Answer (score 4):

The `errors_on` matcher moved to [the rspec-collection_matchers gem](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers), so adding that to your Gemfile would fix the error.

If you wanted to move away from non-core syntax, you could do

```
describe Language do
  describe 'title validation' do
    context 'title is present' do
      before(:each) do
        @lang = Language.new(title: 'English')
      end

      it 'is valid with present title' do
        expect(@lang.errors[:title]).to be_empty
      end
    end

    context 'title is not present' do
      before(:each) do
        @lang = Language.create
      end

      it 'has an error on title attribute' do
        expect(@lang.errors.added?(:title, :blank)).to be_true
      end
    end

  end
end
```

([`have_exactly` and related matchers have also moved to rspec-collection_matchers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24111466/634576))

Answer (score -1):

Try to set type option:

```
describe Language, type: :model do
```

Or use `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` (See [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1026#issuecomment-43638513))

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```